# How can I use the keyword box to add keywords to a sequence of pictures without using the mouse?

Tags: keybindings, aperture

I'm running Aperture 3.6 on Yosemite on a Mac Pro.

In [aperture-tip-rapid-keywording](https://www.scottdavenportphoto.com/blog/2014/2/5/aperture-tip-rapid-keywording) Scott claims that command right-arrow moves the selected image to the next image, while leaving the cursor in the keyword box at the bottom of the screen.

Alas, it doesn't do this.  It does move the selection to the next image but leaves the browser as the active receiver of keystrokes.  I have to click again in the keyword box.

*Addendum:  Turns out this works for the keyword box in the info panel in the inspector, but NOT for the keyword box at the bottom. In addtion all the text in the box is selected.  Gotta love consistency.
So it never did work like this.*

I've dropped Scott a note about this.

I tried with other command arrow options, in case I had command right arrow set to something.  If so I've set all 4 arrow combinations. (Up is the same as right, down the same as left in terms of selection)

How can I use the keyword box to add keywords to a sequence of pictures without using the mouse?

- If this is an arrow reset issue, where can I find out what other app is mucking about with this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually quite simple.
Aperture => Commands => Customize

This brings up means to map any key to any command.

The desired command is "Add New Keyword"  It defaults to being mapped to command backtick, which I find awkward.  I remapped to Command K.  This overwrites a command used for stacks, but I don't use stacks much.

This allows me to go Command right arrow to select the next photo, then command-K to put the cursor in the bottom add keywords window.

Answer (score 0):

It says it right there in his post.

> I have defined a few button sets

It is something you can create using applescript or automator.

Based on Apple's site, the closest action for what you want is:

> 1. In the Browser, select an image or group of images.
> 2. In the control bar, type the new keyword in the Add Keyword field,
>      then press Return.

[image]

**The keyword you entered is now applied to the image or group of images.**

Comment: Button sets get awkward in a hurry.  I currently am using just under a thousand keywords.  The key concept missing, was how to get from the browser to the add keyword window without using the mouse.

Comment: I did not word it the same but the first part of my statement was referring to him mapping that key. In normal situations you can do such with any program under applescripts. I should have thought that a lot of multimedia programs do have internal methods of key mapping.